# How would you use psutil to kill idle processes that exceed over a duration amount of time?

Tags: python, psutil

I'm trying to use psutil to kill a specific process when it's not in use / hasn't been interacted/touched with for a long time, here's what I have currently:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'Application.exe' in proc.name():
        proc.kill()
```

This code only kills the process if it finds it by the name - how would I use psutil to kill idle processes that have exceeded a certain duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `create_time()` to get the process creation time.

Your code should look like:

```
import psutil
import time

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'Application.exe' in proc.name():
        proc_duration = (time.time() - proc.create_time()) % 60
        if proc_duration > 25.0:
            proc.kill()
```

You can also get CPU Usage and other process data using psutil. Hope it helps!

Comment: How would you go about comparing it though? e.g: if a process has been active for more than 25 seconds it'll kill it

Comment: Well, that was only a simplified example since didn't detail the maximum amount of time expected (seconds, hours... days?). If you use timestamps, you can get minutes dividing it by 60, or seconds using the modulo (timestamp % 60)... so you may compare them. You can use time.time() to get current time (instead of datetime.now(), subtract create_time() from it, make the modulo (% 60) of it so you will get the seconds that the process has been running... then compare it (this way you may get rid of the datetime import).

Comment: HAHAHAHA! I didn't realize you were the OP!!! Sorry... I will edit my answer to add a 25 seconds control

Comment: just got it haha, thank you so much! appreciate the explanation on how to do it <3